# I get a weird error when trying to initialize Hive

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

Error: `Unhandled Exception: HiveError: You need to initialize Hive or provide a path to store the box.`

Essentially I have these in my dependencies so everything should be good.

```
  hive: ^1.4.4+1
  hive_flutter: ^0.3.1
  path_provider: ^1.6.27
```

I also have `import 'package:hive/hive.dart';`
and
`import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';` in the file

So I just have

```
void doSomething() async {
    final documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    Hive.init(documentDirectory.path);
  }
```

called.

I do not understand. I think I've done everything correct. Let me know if you need something else.

Answer (score 7):

[Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) needs to be initialized when it runs on Android or iOS, therefore you can use a function like this:

```
Future<Box> openHiveBox(String boxName) async {
    if (!kIsWeb && !Hive.isBoxOpen(boxName)) 
      Hive.init((await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path);
    
    return await Hive.openBox(boxName);
}
```

You'll need to import [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) in order to access `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()`

Answer (score 7):

Try the following code on the main function of your flutter application:

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final appDocumentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(appDocumentDirectory.path);
}
```

Comment: not safe on Web

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are getting this issue because you are not awaiting the `initFlutter`.

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart' as path_provider;


Future<void> yourFunction() async {
  final dbDir = await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

  // init hive
  await Hive.initFlutter(dbDir.path);
  await openYourBox();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should await your init method.

Comment: init method doesn't return Future

Answer (score 1):

Just follow these steps the problem will be solved.
**Import these two packages**

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
```

and then use hive

```
await Hive.initFlutter();
await Hive.openBox('cache');
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, path_provider doesn't support WEB. You can see it here: [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider).

You have to use another directory for WEB. If you are using BLOC as a state management, you could do something like this:

```
if (!kIsWeb) {
    // if android or tablet
    HydratedBloc.storage = await HydratedStorage.build(
        storageDirectory: await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(),
    );
} else {
    // if web
    HydratedBloc.storage = await HydratedStorage.build(
        storageDirectory: HydratedStorage.webStorageDirectory,
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because of a typo:

```
await Hive.initFlutter;
```

should've been

```
await Hive.initFlutter();
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually you don't need use HydratedStorage to initialize Hive on web:

```
import 'package:hive/src/hive_impl.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

initializeHive()async{
  //Use HiveImpl() to ensure you don't have conflicting Hive boxes.
  HiveInterface _hive = HiveImpl();
  if (kIsWeb) {
    await _hive.openBox('yourBoxName');
  } else {
    var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    _hive.init(dir.path);
    await _hive.openBox('yourBoxName');
  }
}
```

If you're using Flutter on web, you don't need to initialize Hive and neither provider a path to box, only if you're using it on mobile.